# Get a word after specific word using regexp_substr in sql oracle

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

I have tried

```
select regexp_substr ('sys: error: This is a message ''123:'' for column EMP_NB', '[[:alpha:]_]+',1,9) from dual
```

I have column filled with this type of data.

```
sys: error: This is a message '123:' for column EMP_NB.  
sys: error: This is a message '45346:' for column EM_NM.  
sys: error: This is a message '78324f9:' for column DEPT_NO_VL.
```

I need an output like below this using regexp_substr in Oracle SQL. The challenge is the length of string tend to change and I need to extract only the characters after the `column` word in string.

Expected outputs:

```
EMP_NB
EM_NM
DEPT_NO_VL
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use

```
select regexp_substr ('sys: error: This is a message ''123:'' for column EMP_NB', 'column[[:space:]]*([[:alpha:]_]+)', 1, 1, NULL, 1) from dual
```

Here,

- `column` - matches `column` word
- `[[:space:]]*` - 0  or more whitespace chars
- `([[:alpha:]_]+)` - captures into Group 1 any one or more letters or underscores.

The value captured is returned only, since the last group ID argument is set to `1`.

Comment: I have tried this too , I could see this is more efficient than the other one. Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

Just anchor the pattern to the end of the string:

```
select regexp_substr('sys: error: This is a message ''123:'' for column EMP_NB', '[[:alpha:]_]+$')
from dual
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=28a928d90f642522418b84763b7588cf) is a db<>fiddle.

Your example data has a period at the end.  If that is part of the string, then you can use `regexp_replace()`:

```
select regexp_replace(message, '^.*[^[:alpha:]_]([[:alpha:]_]+)[^[:alpha:]_]*$', '\1')
from (select 'sys: error: This is a message ''123:'' for column EMP_NB' as message from dual union all
      select 'sys: error: This is a message ''45346:'' for column EM_NM.' as message from dual union all
      select 'sys: error: This is a message ''78324f9:'' for column DEPT_NO_VL.' as message from dual
     ) x
```